# Let $(A,B) \in S_n(\mathbb R)^2$ $\forall X \ne 0, (AX|X) \ge 0 $ Show that $ sp(AB) \subset \mathbb R $

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(A,B) \in S_n(\mathbb R)^2$
$\forall X \ne 0, (AX|X) \ge 0 $
Show that $ sp(AB) \subset \mathbb R $

My work

I took an eigen value of $AB$ to show that it was equal to its conjugate

To do that I considered the product $ \bar{X}^T ABX$ with X the vector associated to the value $\lambda $

It is on the one hand equal to $\lambda \bar{X}^T X$ and on the other hand to $(BA\bar{X})^T X$. However I am blocked here. I don’t know where to use the inner product from here.

Comment: You might check the assumptions: there is no $B$ in the inequality. Also: eigenvalue has nothing to do with the number eight ;)

Comment: @daw sorry, I’m new to doing maths in english :)

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is positive semidefinite so it has a positive semidefinite square root $A^{1/2}$. We get

$$\sigma(AB) =\sigma(A^{1/2}A^{1/2}B) = \sigma(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}) \subseteq \Bbb{R}$$

since $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ is symmetric.